# Determinant of tridiagonal matrix consisting of all $1's$ on the diagonals obeying $a_{ij} = 1 , |i-j| \leq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem asks us to show that for an $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$, that the value of the determinant $|A|$, equals -1, 1, 0 when $n$ equals $3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$, respectively, for some $k\ge 0$.

This is what I am thinking. Induction on k. For k = 0 we have n = 3k $\implies$ $n=0$  which, for a matrix is not defined, and so vacuously $|A| = -1$ is true. $n = 3k+1 \implies n = 1$ and thus $|A| = 1$. Lastly, $n = 3k+2 \implies n=2$, and thus $|A| = 0$.

Now, Assume the statement is true for all integers $j, 0 \leq j \leq k$. Consider then $j = k+1$. Now this is where I am stuck. I was thinking about taking the determinant using minors and cofactors, which has some kind of recursive nature to it using the determinant of a previous one, but I am unable to come up with the correct recursive formula for this. I don't even know if induction is really the smart idea here. Maybe there's a better way, any ideas how to show this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, and $D_n$ its determinant.

Then we find:

$$D_1=|1|=1,\quad D_2=\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

and compute by expanding along the first row

$$D_3=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&1\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=0-1=-1$$

For larger matrices with $n>3$, we find

$$D_n=D_{n-1}-\det(T_{n-1})$$

where $T_{n-1}$ is the same as $A_{n-1}$ but with $t_{21}=0$ instead of $1$. So we can expand $\det(T_{n-1})$ along the first column to get

$$\det(T_{n-1})=\det(A_{n-2})=D_{n-2}$$

Thus we obtain the recursion

$$D_n=D_{n-1}-D_{n-2},\quad n\ge3 \tag{1}$$

Therefore for the first $12$ values:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
D_1=1&D_2=0&D_3=-1&D_4=-1&D_5=0&D_6=1 \\
D_7=1&D_8=0&D_9=-1&D_{10}=-1&D_{11}=0&D_{12}=1 \\
\end{array}$$

Due to the nature of the recursion in (1), values of $D_n$ will repeat with period $6$, for all positive $n$.

This does not agree with the formula proposed in the question, but it should be a small matter to verify directly that $D_4=-1$, say. If you want you can construct a piecewise formula for $D_n$ based on modular arithmetic you can end up with something like

$$D_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n\equiv0,1\pmod{6}\\  
0,&\text{if }n\equiv2,5\pmod{6}\\  
-1,&\text{if }n\equiv3,4\pmod{6}\\  
\end{cases}$$